# How to print a matric or vector to screen returned by a function in theano?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I'm new of theano, when I tried to run this code, I got the response below:

```
  1 import numpy
  2 import theano
  3 import theano.tensor as T
  4 rng = numpy.random
  5 
  6 N = 5
  7 feats = 3
  8 D = (rng.randn(N, feats), rng.randint(size=N, low=0, high=10))
  9 training_steps = 10000
 10 
 11 # Declare Theano symbolic variables
 12 x = T.matrix("x")
 13 y = T.vector("y")
 14 w = theano.shared(rng.randn(feats), name="w")
 15 b = theano.shared(0., name="b")
 16 print "Initial model:"
 17 # Construct Theano expression graph
 18 print T.dot(x, w)
```

Initial model:
dot.0

how can I actually see the value of the returned value, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the expression, which is best done by turning it into a function. Remove line 18 from your code and then add

```
dot_product = T.dot(x, w)
f = theano.function([x], dot_product)

print f(rng.randn(feats))
```